# App link not working after adding juspay dependency in gradle

Tags: android, android-app-links

I have integrated juspay payment gateway in my project, recently I have added Android App Link in my project and don't know somehow juspay dependency is affecting Android App Link result, my app link is not working with Juspay dependency in gradle, If remove Juspay dependency from the Gradle then App link will works perfect.

Comment: Can you add Gradle console output that shows what exactly are the errors?

Comment: @ULazdins Thing is when I'm adding juspay dependency in gradle it'll sync successfully but don't know it is stopping App link to work, If I remove my App link will work, before adding juspay app link open application without asking preference, after adding juspay it's asking for app preference.

Answer (score 1):

Juspay sdk internally has auto verify flag set to true. What this means is that they are trying to verify their Url with your app credentials and failing.

According to app links doc, even if 99 are URLs verified out of 100. Android treats every other URL unverified because of one verification failure. Also, if you set autoverify=true on one intent filter, android will try and verify every URL mentioned in intentfilters without autoverify=true

I faced the same situation and asked them to add our apk key to their assetlinks.json file.

Comment: Thank you @amalBit After facing Applink issue we have reached to Juspay team and they have resolved issue from their side, also they have solved for all. Now, Nobody will face the same issue further.